# Scala machine learning toolbox

Tags: scala, machine-learning

I learn Scala programming language and 
I have interest in machine learning.

Which ML toolboxes are popular in Scala programming?

Comment: (http://www.scalanlp.org/)

Comment: [Smile](https://haifengl.github.io) seems good. Apache Spark ML is complex, sometimes slow, and contains less algorithms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use spark which is part of Hadoop and has a scala API and machine Learning Library (ML LIB).
http://spark.apache.org/